# where can I get land use data for Beijing

Tags: data, china

Iam looking for land use data for Beijing of 1985 and 2010

Comment: its better if you post this to a more suited SE site like Open data...http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited to http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this http://gis.harvard.edu/resources/data/china-gis-data

I've noticed a couple links have Land Use records. Maybe some that you need.